# How can I fix the optional?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

Ich habe versucht das Optional zu löschen aber dann bekomme ich ein Fehler, kann jemand dazu was sagen?

danke.

Google Translate:

> How can I fix the Optional?
>
> I tried to delete the Optional but then I get an error, can someone to
> say something?
>
> thank you.

[image: Link to code]

Comment: You may get help if you rewrite this in English.

Comment: I was thinking which version of swift you are using.

Comment: hey thanks for the translation, im using Xcode 7.0.1.

Comment: Clearly `"B"` is not in your `artikeNr` dictionary, so it returns `nil`.  You are force unwrapping that which is why you are crashing.

Comment: what you suggesting that i can du?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is force unwrapping all of the optionals, which defeats the purpose of having optionals in the first place. You declared Pricelist to be an optional, which means it may be a Produkt or it may be nil. You can refactor your code using guard statements instead but there are issues with the implementation. For example, you should not be requesting a table cell if there is no data to show. I would say it is probably better if PriceList is not an optional (or check to see if it is empty before invoking this method).

Answer (score 0):

You should use `if` statement like this

```
if let B = art["B"] { then use variable B here }
```

to safely unwrap optional value then your code will not crash due to nil values. There is one more thing which you should do is remove breakpoint. I can see a breakpoint which will break the code there.

Comment: What is there on your line 41?

Comment: let artikelNr = priceListe!.price[indexPath.row]

Comment: I think you have not deleted breakpoint in that line. Double click on the blue mark and delete that. Let me know if you're facing same error.

Comment: And one more thing your variable 'pricelist' is empty which may be is causing the issue.

Comment: The variable pricelist is getting his value from the First ViewController with segue, and i gut this breakpoint but it still making an Error Thread.

Comment: Yeah, so first check if that 'pricelist' is empty or not then use that variable.